# RedactorJS: linebreaks true -> Alignment does not work

Tags: redactor

I use the RedactorJS as my WYSIWYG editor.

Initialize redactor:

```
$( '#myeditor' ).redactor( { linebreaks: true } )
```

Then the alignment does not work anymore. Set `linebreak:false`(this is default) than everything is ok.
Are there any solutions?

Answer from the Redactor support

> The reason is that we'll have to wrap your lines with a div to apply alignment, and many customers didn't want this to happen. However, we are considering changes in this behavior and may allow such wrapping and alignment soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fixed in Version 9.0.3:
http://imperavi.com/redactor/log/

Answer (score 4):

The alignement is apply on `<p>` element, so your problem is logic. You must create a plugin that adds a frame around the content selected. Then you change the alignment value. You can modify `alignmentSet` function on `redactor.js`

> Redactor support should fix it.

It is fixed in Version 9.0.3: http://imperavi.com/redactor/log/